# How to find the line integral from $(0,0)$ to $(1/8,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to find the line integral from $(0,0)$ to $(1/8,0)$. I just want to know if what I did is correct.

$x=x$ and $y=0$ where $x$ is less than or equal to $0$ and greater than or equal to $1/8$.

I took the integral from $0$ to $1/8$ of $1dx$. However, I have to find the jacobian. The jacobian is the square root of the square of $dx/dx$ plus the square of $dy/dx$. Doing this I got square root of $(1)^2 + (0)^2 = 1$

So my integral is now just $1dx$ from $0$ to $1/8$. Solving this I get $1/8$.

Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a line integral over a path $\gamma$ with velocity $v$ as

$ \int _ \gamma v dt = \int _ \gamma  \sqrt { \left ( \frac{ dx}{dt} \right ) ^2  +  \left ( \frac{dy}{dt} \right )^2 } dt$

You won't need the jacobian since we're not changing coordinates (that's when it'll show up). That path we're moving along in your case is

$ \gamma(t) = (t , 0 )$

we travel from $t = 0$ to $t=1/8$ so we end up doing exactly what you said.

$ \int_0^{1/8} dt = \frac{1}{8} $